# Compiler cannot find IEnumerable.Append but can find Union and other extensions

Tags: c#, linq, resharper

I'm trying to use the IEnumerable.Append extension method but Visual Studio 2017 complains that it does not exist.  Yet at the same time, *can* find other extension methods such as Union.  That makes no sense to me.

Does anyone know what I am missing?

- I am the importing both System.Collections.Generic and System.Linq namespaces.
- I do have a reference to System.Core in my project.
- I cannot find any assembly named "System.Linq" to add a reference to in the Reference Manager, though I've seen that recommendation before.
- The only assemblies I see with "Linq" in the title are System.Xml.Linq and System.Data.Linq.  Tried adding those but that did not help (nor did I expect it to)
- Although Visual Studio cannot find Append, it appears that Resharper somehow can.  More on that below.

Is there some other assembly I must add a reference to?  Or is this some newer extension method?  I'm targeting .NET 4.7 and later on a Windows 10 box

Here's some sample code I whipped up and put right in my same source file to illustrate the problem.

```
// Using statements.

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

// Append fails to build but Union succeeds...???

IEnumerable<int> vals1 = new List<int>{ 0, 1, 2 };
IEnumerable<int> vals2 = new List<int>{ 3, 4, 5 };
IEnumerable<int> vals3 = vals1.Append(7);    //<-- ERROR.  "Append" not found
IEnumerable<int> vals4 = vals1.Union(vals2);
```

One weird thing:  To try to figure this out, I clicked "Go to Definition" on the "Union" function name.  It took me to a decompiled version of Enumerable.cs in the JetBrains decompiler cache.  There I saw the implemention of Union ***and I saw an implementation of Append.***

That seemed weird.  So as an experiment, I tried disabling Resharper and clicking "Go to Definition" again.  This time it took me to a Visual Studio decompiled Enumerable.cs which has Union but does not have Append.

Comment: [Enumerable.Append](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.append?view=netframework-4.7.2) was added in .NET 4.7.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler is right; this method was added in .NET Framework 4.7.1 - I imagine JetBrains is obtaining reference source without filtering to version. So: change to 4.7.1, or live without the method.

You can see the version history under ["Applies To" in MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.append#applies-to)